# How can I download the video description of a YouTube video without downloading the video with youtube-dl?

Tags: download, youtube-dl

How can I download the video description of a YouTube video without downloading the video with youtube-dl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following options:

- `--write-description`
- `--skip-download`
- `--youtube-skip-dash-manifest`

*Example*

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o0r9unT4L4 --write-description --skip-download --youtube-skip-dash-manifest
```

Descriptions are downloaded as `.description` files, which are just normal text files.

---

*Note that if a video description is blank, a 0-byte file will be produced.*

---

**References**

[youtube-dl - Only download descriptions - Issue #8593](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/8593)

[youtube-dl - Official Documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md)